# I like to delete oracle table multiple records through vb.net datagridview, ora 00936 missing expression error is come for below coding

Tags: vb.net

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In selectedRows
    Dim str As String

    str = "DELETE from sheet1 WHERE Id = @Id"

    Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(str, con)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("@Id", row.Cells("Id").Value))

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
Next
```

I like to delete oracle table multiple records through vb.net `DataGridView`, `ora` 00936 missing expression error is come for below coding.. if im using `AddWithValue` instead of cmd.parameter.add then the error is `AddWithValue` is not a member of `oracle.dataAccess.client.oracleparametercollection`..
Please help me..

Comment: I don't really use Oracle but I don't think that it supports "@" as a parameter prefix. That's a Microsoft thing. As for `AddWithValue`, don't use it anyway. Call `Add` and provide the name, data type and optionally the size, then set the `Value` property of the parameter. That avoids issues with mismatched data types that can arise from `AddWithValue`.

Comment: For Oracle, use `:` instead of `@`, so `:Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the connection and command outside the loop. The only thing that changes inside the loop is the value of the parameter. Open the connection once outside the loop.

`CommandType.Text` is the default value for `.CommandType` and doesn't need to explicitly stated.

Use a `Using...End Using` block to insure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Notice the parameter name is preceded by a colon in the `.CommandText`. When the parameter name is provided to the Parameter constructor there is no colon. I have not tested this. This is info from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8 Check the last paragraph in Remarks.

```
Private Sub OPCode(selectedRows As List(Of DataGridViewRow))
    Using con As New OracleConnection("Your connection String"),
            cmd As New OracleCommand("DELETE from sheet1 WHERE Id = :Id", con)
        'This will bind parameters by name instead of the order they appear in the command text.
        cmd.BindByName = True
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", OracleDbType.Int32)
        con.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In selectedRows
            cmd.Parameters("Id").Value = row.Cells("Id").Value))
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```